# ruby / OS X cannot open existing file in iPhoto Library

Tags: ruby, osx-yosemite, iphoto

env:  OSX 10.10 / iPhoto 9.6 / Ruby 2.2

in a ruby script, I am trying to open an xml file from the 'iPhoto Library' to get the album list..  but I got an error :

```
 f = File.open(@xmlpath)
 Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/myself/Pictures/iPhoto%20Library/AlbumData.xml
```

first, I defined the 'iPhoto Library' path in my user path :

```
PhotoLib = File.expand_path(File.join("~","Pictures","iPhoto Library")
```

then I defined the @xml file path ( escaping the embedded spaces )

```
 @xmlpath = URI.escape(File.join iPhotoLib, "AlbumData.xml")
```

finally I try to open the xml file

```
 f = File.open(@xmlpath)
```

but it raises the 'No such file or directory' error...  where am I wrong ?
the file exists in the "iPhoto Library" content  ...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `URI.escape` - that is for urls but what you pass to `File.open` is a path on your local filesystem, not a url. In particular percentage escapes ("%20") don't make sense to your filesystem

Comment: ok,  you're right ...however I found my error .. I should use   Pathname.new     :  library_path = Pathname.new(ENV["HOME"]) + "Pictures" + "iPhoto Library.photolibrary" , then  the path would be correct ...

Answer (score 0):

I should use

library_path = Pathname.new(ENV["HOME"]) + "Pictures" + "iPhoto Library.photolibrary"
xml_path = library_path + "AlbumData.xml"
f = File.open(xml_path)

Pathname handle correctly it ....